# How to find most frequent string in file

Tags: bash

I have a question about bash script, lets say there is file witch contains lines, each line will have path to a file and a date, the problem is how to find most frequent path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a example line?

Comment: /home/admin/file jan:17:13:46:27:2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion

```
$ cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n1
# \_____________________/  \__/   \_____/   \______/   \_______/
# select the file column   sort    print     sort on    print top
#                          files   counts    count       result
```

Example use:

```
$ cat file.txt 
/home/admin/fileA jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileB jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileC jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileA jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileA jan:17:13:46:27:2015
$ cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n1
       3 /home/admin/fileA
```

You can strip out `3` from the final result by another `cut`.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning this may fail if there's whitespace on the paths, depending on field position

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the lines, cut the begginning (the date), reverse them again, then sort and count unique lines:

`cat file.txt | rev | cut -b 22- | rev | sort | uniq -c`

If you're absolutely sure you won't have whitespace in your paths, you can avoid `rev` altogether:

`cat file.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq -c`

If the output is too long to inspect visually, aioobe's suggestion of following this with `sort -rn | head -n1` will serve you well

---

It's worth noticing, as aioobe mentioned, that many unix commands optionally take a file argument. By using it, you can avoid the extra `cat` command in the beginning, by supplying its argument to the next command:

`cat file.txt | rev | ...` vs `rev file.txt | ...`

While I personally find the first option both easier to remember and understand, the second is preferred by many (most?) people, as it saves up system resources (specifically, the memory and references used by an additional process) and can have better performance in some specific use cases. [Wikipedia's `cat` article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) discusses this in detail.

Comment: Unnecessary use of cat?

Comment: @aioobe absolutely. My personal opinion is that the memory taken by a additional process on the OS is cheaper than the space taken in *my* memory in remembering which commands accept file arguments and which don't, and in which order - or the time it takes me to read the manual. YMMV.

Comment: Ok. I'm of the opinion that when trying to help/teach someone something new it's good to follow best practices. In this case I knew cut accepted a file and checking the case for rev was just a --help away. Personally I think it's worth the effort.

Comment: @aioobe that's true, it's not a great effort. I'm not sure if it's a best practice, but I've edited the answer to explain the difference so everyone can make an informed choice. Feel free to further edit if you think it's biased in any way

Comment: There's even an abbreviation for it: [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) :-)

Comment: @aioobe thanks for that, I hadn't thought about `seek` at all. I just tested it with `sort`, and the difference is very considerable!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use cut as suggestion above. You can use awk as well.
Here's my suggestion:

```
awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n10
```

Comment: You forgot to give input file to `awk`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: less file.txt | awk -F' ' '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n10
take the result of less file.txt and use pipeline to take that result as input of command above. I give suggestion instead of using cut command.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
/home/admin/fileA jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileB jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileC with blanks jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileC with blanks jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileC with blanks jan:17:13:46:27:2015
/home/admin/fileA jan:17:13:46:27:2015  

$ awk -F' [^ ]*$' '
    {
        cnt[$1]++
        if(cnt[$1] > fq) {
            fq = cnt[$1]
            path = $1
        } 
    }
    END{ print path }
' file

/home/admin/fileC with blanks
```